# Grunt SASS Watch not working

Tags: sass, gruntjs, jekyll

I have a grunt file as shown below. The problem I am having is when I change the contents of a .scss file, grunt watch sass does not trigger a refresh. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    build : {
        dest: '_site'
    },

    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed',
          trace: true
        },
        files: {
          'css/main.css': '_scss/main.scss',
          'css/ie8.css': '_scss/ie8.scss',
          'css/ie9.css': '_scss/ie9.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    shell: {
      jekyllBuild: {
        command: 'jekyll build'
      },
      jekyllServe: {
        command: 'jekyll serve'
      }
    },

    watch: {
      files: ['_layouts/*.html', '*.md', '*.yml'],
      // SASS watch does not work  :(
      sass: {
        files: ['_scss/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:dist'] // This should be sass'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jekyll');

  // Compiles SASS, Builds Jekyll, and Serves Jekyll.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dist', 'shell:jekyllBuild', 'shell:jekyllServe']);
}
```

Also when I change a .scss file, the terminal indicates that a file has been changed but grunt watch sass does not run.

```
Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2015-08-05 13:14:50 ...done in 0.017384 seconds.
```

**EDIT**:

I figured it out. What I was attempting to do was use grunt to watch my sass files and re-compile when changes were made. I also wanted jekyll to serve & watch the html files for changes. These things cannot be ran concurrently which was what I was attempting to do. I did happen to find a helper called 'load-grunt-tasks' which allows for concurrent tasks to be ran by adding the following code to the gruntfile:

```
concurrent: {
    serve: [
        'sass',
        'watch',
        'shell:jekyllServe'
    ],
    options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
    }
},

// Then register the following tasks
// Register the grunt serve task
grunt.registerTask('serve', ['concurrent:serve']);

// Then run the following from the terminal: 
grunt serve
```

Answer (score 1):

At first some general troubleshooting:

- Did you made sure all dependencies are properly installed? `npm install`
- Are all dependencies up to date? `npm update`
- I see that you're using Jekyll, why do you introduce Grunt at this point? Jekyll comes with its own `watch` task. This may produce some errors.

---

```
watch: {
    files: ['_layouts/*.html', '*.md', '*.yml'],
    // SASS watch does not work  :(
    sass: {
        files: ['_scss/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:dist']
    }
}
```

This looks kinda broken to me. What is `watch` supposed to do with `files: [...]`? There is no task to be executed while watching over these files. You don't have any `grunt tasks` which would modify `.html`, `.md` or `.yml` files, so why do you even list them?

Apart from that, it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you're using Grunt for this? Jekyll comes with a perfectly fine Sass watcher, and if you want to carry out any further pre/post-processing tasks you can do so using Jekyll's plugin system.

You can place your `.scss`/`.sass` files in `_sass`, and call them from a `.scss`/`.sass` file located anywhere else that starts with some YAML frontmatter.

A common structure would be something like this:

```
- _scss/
  - normalize.scss
  - typography.scss
  - [whatever].scss
- assets/
  - main.scss
```

With `assets/main.scss` containing the following:

```
---
# You just need these --- lines to tell Jekyll to parse this file.
---

@import "normalize";
@import "typography";
@import [...]

// Other styles too
body {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: {{ site.branding.color }}; // Can even use Jekyll variables
}
```

As far as plugins go, I'm using [octopress-autoprefixer](https://github.com/octopress/autoprefixer) to automatically prefix CSS3 properties. The process for using this plugin is as follows:

1. `gem install octopress-autoprefixer`
2. Add this to your `_config.yml`:

   ```
   gems:
     - octopress-autoprefixer
   ```
3. That's it.

Now when you make any changes to your Sass, after the CSS files are generated in `_site/`, autoprefixer will do it's magic to them.

Comment: Interesting. I was not able to get this to work. There are a lot of the examples floating around on the internet which describe using grunt as the approach to this problem. Perhaps the bigger problem is offering better documentation on this b/c a lot of the examples I'm seeing are using grunt. I found this bit of info: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/ Even when adding this sass config params to the _config.yml. Nothing happens. My structure is setup as <source>/_scss/ which should output to <source>/css/ but it doesn't work. Currently grunt approach works but would rather do it the proper way.

Comment: Also as a test to see if this is working. I deleted all of the compiled files from the css/ directory,  ran jeykll serve, and finally edited and saved a sass file. Jeykll notices that one file has been changed "Regenerating: 1 file(s)" but no files are compiled into the css/ directory.